# с# вставка в mysql координаты Google Earth

Tags: c#

не получается вставить координаты Google Earth через формы текстбокс в базу данных Mysql. я хочу вставить в базу данных координаты через текстбокс после координаты должны отображаться в датагриде, при нажатии конкретной координаты пользователь должен перейти по Google Earth на определенную точку.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApp9
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("google");
    private MySqlCommand command;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server = 192.130.1.1; UserId = admin; Password = 12345; database = telecom");
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    public void spisok()
    {
        con.Open();

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(" SELECT* FROM `google` ", con);
        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dset);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        con.Close();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        spisok();
    }
    private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
    {
        spisok();
        con.Open();
        command = con.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = txtQuery;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "insert into google(id, name, geoc, geob) Values (@id, @name, @geoc, @geob)";


        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 100).Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = textBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@geoc", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = textBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@geob", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = textBox4.Text;
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Added");
        }

        con.Close();


        spisok();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста покажите код

Comment: исправил, выложил код

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32, 100).Value = textBox1.Text; - мне кажется, неплохо бы к Int32 текст преобразовать, как то так: Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)

Comment: Ошибка какая?..

Comment: ошибка в том что не вставляется в нужном формате , тоесть  ( широта 37°34'18.82"С , долгота  61°52'50.56"В)

Comment: мне нужно в таком формате вставить в базу , после отображать в датагриде , потом хочу как-то коннектит это дело с google earth (пока не представляю как это сделать). но для начало хотя бы вставить координаты правильно в базу и отображать их

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что значения широты и долготы, это числа? Почему вы решили в базе это хранить как текст?

Comment: согласен, это просто для примера , мне нужно хранить символы , вот это беда

Comment: Сделайте отдельные колонки в бд для долготы, широты итд (float), а в C# получайте и работайте с google earth